# How to switch focus between buttons in MacVim's 'file changed' popup

Tags: vim, macvim

When a file opened in MacVim is modified outside of it and I return to the editor, a popup appears with text: `W11: Warning: File "foo.txt" has changed since editing started
See ":help W11" for more info.` - I don't want to click with mouse, I'd rather stay on the keyboard. The focus is on 'OK' button, but I want to click 'Load All'. Using `TAB` to switch doesn't work, how can I it with just the keyboard?

Version of MacVim 7.4 (build 73), homebrew installed with janus plugin pack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question has *nothing* to do with Vim, MacVim, Homebrew, Janus or even programming.

1. In the "Apple" menu, choose "System Preferences…".
2. Under "Hardware", click on "Keyboard".
3. Under "Full keyboard access", check "All controls".

You can now use <kbd>⇥</kbd> and <kbd>⇤</kbd> to move the focus from button to button and <kbd>Space</kbd> to "click" on non-default buttons.

Enjoy your new Mac.

**edit**

There's a Vim-only solution, though, you can remove those GUI dialogs altogether with:

```
set guioptions+=c
```

Comment: There should be a way to disable the popup completely in MacVim and get the normal terminal vim prompt when this happens. (I don't have it on me so I can't check)